# Complexity of an instance of a NP-complete problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

I am trying to prove the NP-Completeness of problem **[A]**.

I know there is a well-known NP-Complete problem called problem **[B]**.

I can model **[A]** into an instance of **[B]** (**[B]** is a very general problem and when I assign some edges a weight value then it becomes **[A]**).

Is this sufficient to say **[A]** is NP-Complete?

Comment: Try emulating what you saw in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show $A$ is NP-complete, you need to prove the following:

1. $A \in \mathbf{NP}$
2. $A$ is *NP-hard*: any problem $B \in \mathbf{NP}$ is *poly-time* (many-one) reducible to $A$

   **or**

   equivalently (because reduction relations are transitive): there is an NP-hard problem $B$ which is *poly-time* (many-one) reducible to $B$.

You have shown neither, so you cannot say $A$ is NP-complete.

What you did do is a many-one reduction from $A$ to $B$, but you want *the other way around*. In addition, you also need to show the reduction is *efficient*, that is, takes polynomial time; you did not explicitly state whether this is the case. And, of course, you must not forget to show $A \in \mathbf{NP}$ (which is usually the easier part).